# Make Notes and Messages in Careers Candidates Popup Distinct

Tags: feature-request, jobs

"History & Notes" and "Messages" are too close together, and look very similar.  It is very easy to make a mistake and send notes to a candidate as a message.  I have caught myself at the last second a few times.

It would be pretty embarrassing to send notes like "this guy is not any good" to a candidate.

Comment: It's also embarrassing when you *think* you've sent a message and it's instead been stuffed in History & Notes ([more on that issue here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177530/why-does-clicking-the-mail-icon-next-to-a-careers-candidate-bring-up-the-history)).