# Why does clicking the mail icon next to a careers candidate bring up the History&Notes tab?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

### Clicking the mail icon on a Careers candidate does not bring up the Messages tab for a reply; it instead brings up the History & Notes tab so you have the freedom to *think* you've replied, while all you've done is leave a note-to-self regarding the appointment you *think* you've scheduled with the applicant.

Current behavior: Clicking on a candidate always displays the `History & Notes` tab, regardless of which tab you were using last. Messages are displayed nearly identically in History & Notes so there are no secondary visual clues that the message you thought you send was in fact a note-to-self.

This is truly terrible UX behavior in my opinion.

I would suggest one or more of the following solutions

1. Remember the selected tab for each given candidate.
2. Remember the last selected tab, regardless of candidate.
3. Default to display the Messages tab when there are new messages.
4. Just default to the Messages tab if there are any messages present.
5. Default to *any* other tab except the **Deceptive History & Notes Tab Of Doom.**
6. Make the candidate 'blurbs' have individually clickable regions. Say - clicking the name/profile images brings up the Profile, clicking the red Mail icon brings up messages, and clicking the description brings up History & Notes.

Any of these solutions would make this system less horribly error-prone.

If the current behavior was an over-correction from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130919/make-notes-and-messages-in-careers-candidates-popup-distinct), I urge you to find a balance. Perhaps different accent colors within the tabs, even?

Comment: Why? => *It's a feature!*

Comment: Your sarcasm deserves an upvote :)